# Iterating through a list of objects and displaying the property in the combobox

Tags: c#

I have 2 combo boxes, the first one lets you pick an interface and the second one should display the appropriate addresses depending on which interface you chose, I have a list of objects, each object is an interface with associated addresses.  I need to display these addresses to the combo box after the user chooses what interface to connect to.

Here is what I have so far and the problem is that it always displays the addresses for the first interface.  The AddressCnt is the number of addresses for each interface.

```
    private void cboInterface_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblAddress.Text = cboInterface.SelectedItem.ToString();
        cboAddress.Items.Clear();

        for (int x = 0; x < Interface[0].AddressCnt; x++)
        {
            cboAddress.Items.Add(Interface[0].AddressBuff[x].ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Ok so I modified the for loop and its working fine now, I just passed the selected index of the combo box instead of 0.

Comment: Since you figured out your issue, you should post your solution as an answer and accept it. That way other people will know if they have the same issue.